# regex to match file names

Tags: java, regex, file

I have a java class and 
I want to read files which have names starting with "home-search-log.log". So I have written this code.

```
  File dir = new File("D:\\");
   File[] foundFiles = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {

        return Pattern.compile("^(home-search-log.log)").matcher(file.getName()).matches();
    }
   });
   for (File file : foundFiles) {
       System.out.println(file.getName());
   }
```

But it is returning only one file which has exact name as given. Name of my other file is "home-search-log.log.2013-04-12" but it is not returned by this pattern. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you searched through SO? There are so many previous answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code could be better:

```
return file.getName().startsWith("home-search-log.log");
```

Comment: Does the `.` not need to be escaped i.e. `\.`?

Comment: String.startsWith() just compare this 2 strings,no need to escape anything

Answer (score 1):

Try below regular expression.

```
System.out.println("home-search-log.log.2013-04-12".matches("^home-search-log.*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
"^(home-search-log\\.log.*)"
```

First you need to escape the special chars used in regex ("-",".") and add the end to specify that you want to match anything ".*" so in this case it should match anything from "home-search-log.log" to "home-search-log.logsomething"

Comment: the hyphens don't need escaping outside of a character class

Comment: it says "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: sorry about that the dot was not escaped properly , pls try now

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows;

```
"home-search-log.log((.\\d[4]-\\d[2]-\\d[2])?)"
```

Comment: it says "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: I have edited my answer. This should work for both the cases of just a log file as home-search-log.log & home-search-log.log.2013-11-09